# Ruby Hash parsed_response error

Tags: ruby, xml, hash

BACKGROUND

I am using HTTParty to parse an XML hash response.   Unfortunately, when the hash response only has one entry(?), the resulting hash is not indexable.  I have confirmed the resulting XML syntax is the same for single and multiple entry(?).    I have also confirmed my code works when there are always multiple entries(?) in the hash.

QUESTION

How do I accommodate the single hash entry case and/or is there an easier way to accomplish what I am trying to do?

CODE

```
require 'httparty'

  class Rest
    include HTTParty
    format :xml
  end


  def test_redeye
    # rooms and devices
    roomID = Hash.new
    deviceID = Hash.new { |h,k| h[k] = Hash.new }
    rooms = Rest.get(@reIp["theater"] + "/redeye/rooms/").parsed_response["rooms"]
    puts "rooms #{rooms}"   
    rooms["room"].each do |room|
        puts "room #{room}"
        roomID[room["name"].downcase.strip] = "/redeye/rooms/" + room["roomId"] 
        puts "roomid #{roomID}" 
        devices = Rest.get(@reIp["theater"] + roomID[room["name"].downcase.strip] + "/devices/").parsed_response["devices"]
        puts "devices #{devices}"
        devices["device"].each do |device|
            puts "device #{device}"
            deviceID[room["name"].downcase.strip][device["displayName"].downcase.strip] = "/devices/" + device["deviceId"] 
            puts "deviceid #{deviceID}"
        end
    end 
    say "Done"
  end
```

XML - SINGLE ENTRY

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<devices>
  <device manufacturerName="Philips" description="" portType="infrared" deviceType="0" modelName="" displayName="TV" deviceId="82" />
</devices>
```

XML - MULTIPLE ENTRY

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<devices>
  <device manufacturerName="Denon" description="" portType="infrared" deviceType="6" modelName="Avr-3311ci" displayName="AVR" deviceId="77" />
  <device manufacturerName="Philips" description="" portType="infrared" deviceType="0" modelName="" displayName="TV" deviceId="82" />
</devices>
```

RESULTING ERROR

```
[Info - Plugin Manager] Matches, executing block
rooms {"room"=>[{"name"=>"Home Theater", "currentActivityId"=>"78", "roomId"=>"-1", "description"=>""}, {"name"=>"Living", "currentActivityId"=>"-1", "roomId"=>"81", "description"=>"2nd Floor"}, {"name"=>"Theater", "currentActivityId"=>"-1", "roomId"=>"80", "description"=>"1st Floor"}]}
room {"name"=>"Home Theater", "currentActivityId"=>"78", "roomId"=>"-1", "description"=>""}
roomid {"home theater"=>"/redeye/rooms/-1"}
devices {"device"=>[{"manufacturerName"=>"Denon", "description"=>"", "portType"=>"infrared", "deviceType"=>"6", "modelName"=>"Avr-3311ci", "displayName"=>"AVR", "deviceId"=>"77"}, {"manufacturerName"=>"Philips", "description"=>"", "portType"=>"infrared", "deviceType"=>"0", "modelName"=>"", "displayName"=>"TV", "deviceId"=>"82"}]}
device {"manufacturerName"=>"Denon", "description"=>"", "portType"=>"infrared", "deviceType"=>"6", "modelName"=>"Avr-3311ci", "displayName"=>"AVR", "deviceId"=>"77"}
deviceid {"home theater"=>{"avr"=>"/devices/77"}}
device {"manufacturerName"=>"Philips", "description"=>"", "portType"=>"infrared", "deviceType"=>"0", "modelName"=>"", "displayName"=>"TV", "deviceId"=>"82"}
deviceid {"home theater"=>{"avr"=>"/devices/77", "tv"=>"/devices/82"}}
room {"name"=>"Living", "currentActivityId"=>"-1", "roomId"=>"81", "description"=>"2nd Floor"}
roomid {"home theater"=>"/redeye/rooms/-1", "living"=>"/redeye/rooms/81"}
devices {"device"=>{"manufacturerName"=>"Philips", "description"=>"", "portType"=>"infrared", "deviceType"=>"0", "modelName"=>"", "displayName"=>"TV", "deviceId"=>"82"}}
device ["manufacturerName", "Philips"]
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374@SiriProxy/gems/siriproxy-0.3.2/plugins/siriproxy-redeye/lib/siriproxy-redeye.rb:145:in `[]': can't convert String into Integer (TypeError)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of options I see. If you control the endpoint, you could modify the XML being sent to [accomodate HTTParty's underlying XML parser, Crack](https://github.com/jnunemaker/crack/blob/322e0035c4ef1a1410192942b4a62ac861cf3c3a/test/xml_test.rb#L359-L378) by putting a `type="array"` attribute on the `devices` XML element.

Otherwise, you could check to see what class the device is before indexing into it:

```
case devices["device"]
when Array
  # act on the collection
else
  # act on the single element
end
```

It's much less than ideal whenever you have to do type-checking in a dynamic language, so if you find yourself doing this more than once it may be worth introducing polymorphism or at the very least extracting a method to do this.

Comment: I used the case method until the manufacturer gets back to me.